# WPF Pass data from View to ViewModel in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have **ListBox** with list of notes (**NoteList**) that represented by the **Note** **Model** (subject, text, id):

```
<ListBox x:Name="NotesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding NoteList}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UserControls:NoteHeadControl/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

**ListItem** I created in separate **UserControl** (**NoteHeadControl**). Was decided to pass **Id** by **Tag** property. I`m not sure that it is the best way of doing this, but I don't know how to do it other way.

```
    <Button Name="OpenButton" Tag="{Binding id}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding subject}"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding DeleteNoteCommand}" Name="DeleteNoteButton" Content="Delete"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Button>
```

For **NoteHeadControl** I created separate **ViewModel** (**NoteHeadControlViewModel**
) where my commands and properties should be. For example, I want to create a DELETE button on note to delete it from my database. For this **Id** parameter is required in **NoteHeadControlViewModel**.

The problem happens when I try to pass **Id** data from **View** to **ViewModel**:

```
    public NoteHeadControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NoteHeadControlViewModel noteHeadControlViewModel = new NoteHeadControlViewModel((int)this.OpenButton.Tag);
        DataContext = noteHeadControlViewModel;
    }
```

It seems that **UserControl** is not completely initialized at the moment when `(int)this.OpenButton.Tag` is run and **OpenButton** is just not found (**null**).

The question is, how can I pass data (**Id** in my case) from **Window** -> **UserControl** -> **UserControl`s ViewModel** ?

I tried to set **Tag** property not in the **Button**, but in **UserControl** controller. UserControl is initialized, but the property is still **null**.

This task has so many steps and so many of my decision looks kind of strange (I`m still learning and most of them I found here or on other resources) so I don't know where I have done the biggest mistake or what I don't know to resolve the issue by myself.

Comment: you could try to use the loaded event 
after InitializeComponent(); attach to the Loaded Event. 
Loaded += NoteHeadControl_Loaded;
private void NoteHeadControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {...yourcodehere...} but i don't know if that violates the mvvm pattern that i am not a fan of but thats a different story...

Comment: The `UserControl` should not have its own view model. It should inherit the `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For NoteHeadControl I created separate ViewModel (NoteHeadControlViewModel ) where my commands and properties should be.

This is wrong. The `UserControl` should not have its own view model. It should inherit the `DataContext` from the parent element.

What you can do is to add an `ICommand` dependency property to the `NoteHeadControl` and bind this one to a command of the parent view model that should be responsible for deleting the item:

```
<UserControls:NoteHeadControl DeleteCommand="{Binding DataContext.DeleteNoteCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

In the control, you then bind the `Command` property of the `Button` to the dependency property:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
        Content="Delete"/>
```

But don't break the `DataContext` inheritance by explicitly setting the `DataContext` of the control like this:

```
NoteHeadControlViewModel noteHeadControlViewModel = new NoteHeadControlViewModel((int)this.OpenButton.Tag);
DataContext = noteHeadControlViewModel;
```